# restrain vs refrain

Tags: word-choice

I want to avoid answering something as it is out of scope of my role, which of the following sentence will be appropriate.

I will restrain myself from answering as it is not deployment issue.

or

I will refrain myself from answering as it is not deployment issue

Comment: *Restrain* takes an object, so the first is correct; the second would be correct and substantially identical if you left out the word "myself".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"I will restrain myself from answering as it is not a deployment issue" and "I will refrain from answering as it is not a deployment issue" (note no "myself" in the second one) both mean pretty much the same thing: You want to answer it but you're not going to.

I'd say that "restrain myself" implies a **stronger urge to answer**, and is more **humorous**. It is not quite a figure of speech, but it could make the reader picture the writer pulling their struggling-to-type-something hand away from the keyboard or something similar to that, i.e., of being literally restrained, like a struggling mental patient or somesuch. "Refrain from," on the other hand, is dryer, and also has a mild implication that the writer might consider it beneath them to answer.

So, more or less the same thing, but with different, subtle implications.

Answer (score 1):

Restrain is to hold something back whereas refrain is to hold oneself back, so to refrain myself would be saying "I hold myself back myself." So "I refrain" or "I restrain myself" would be correct either way.